# Two links overlapping

Tags: html, hyperlink, overlapping

ive got a problem with HTML.

Ive got a linking div that contains a linking image. When I click on the image, i get both (image's and div's) links opening, whereas I'd like to open just the image one.

How can I make it work? I need that when I click on the entire div, except for the image area, I get to the div's link, otherwise on the image's one.

Thanks in advance,
Alessio

Comment: can you provide  code  so that we able to check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way:-

```
function func1()
{
window.location.href="http://www.google.com";

}

function func2()
{
window.location.href="http://www.yahoo.com";

}
```

HTML CODE

```
 <div id="divid" >
 <div onclick="func1()"> Some text to fill the space... blah blah blah</span></div>
<img id="imgid" onclick="func2()" src="SOMEIMAGE" />
</div>
```

Comment: You can put everything except image in a separate div which must be inside the main div.

Comment: thank you, but this way i dont get what i want. i mean, my image is in the center (by both width and height) of the div, so this method wont provide the solution i was looking for...

Comment: anyway, i finally followed your direction and i adapted my code to make it suitable for your code ;) thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
<div id="mydiv" onclick="window.location.href=('Somepage.aspx')">
  Some text to fill the space... blah blah blah<br />
  <img id="myimg" onclick="window.location.href=('AnotherPage.html')" src="thisphoto.gif" />
</div>
```

## Update

You can add a script to cancel the bubble and then forward to the page you want
Its maybe two or three lines

```
<script type="text/vbscript" id="CancelMyBubble">
  function CancelMyBubble(link)
    window.event.cancelBubble = true
    window.location.href=link
  end function
</script>


<div id="mydiv" onclick="window.location.href=('Somepage.aspx')">
  Some text to fill the space... blah blah blah<br />
  <img id="myimg" src="shape1.jpg" onclick="CancelMyBubble('AnotherPage.html')" />
</div>
```

Comment: thanks but ive already tried it and it goes always to somepage.aspx also when I click the image, because it's part of the div :(